# Where can i see App Service azure logs in Azure Portal

Tags: azure

I have read several docs and tutorials about Azure App Services.

What i want to do is to see my application log (errors, exceptions, etc.) in azure portal.

I have read i need to configure something in order to store my logs to a Storage account, Log analytics, or Event Hub.

But, this command line shows me the logs !

```
az webapp log tail --name myapp --resource-group mygroup
```

So there is no need to configure anything in order to collect log, if this command can do it...

How can i do the same thing in azure portal ?

And how can i see more than 10 lines with this tail ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find using "Log Stream" very useful. It outputs all your logs in realtime to the portal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging on the app service by browsing to the app service logs section under the app service blade in the azure portal. Here is a link that shows how to do it: https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2019/11/01/azure-app-service-and-diagnostics-logging/

Here is another article that shows how to enable diagnostic logging on the app service from the portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs

In terms of the tailing command, the documentation doesn't have any params to do this so I doubt it you can increase the number of lines. However, you can output your logs with -o which you might already know.

Comment: In fact I do not understand why I have to enable something. The log is already enabled because I can see output in az command line...

Comment: @Bob5421 This will then dump logs into your storage accounts. What happens when your web app is down? How will you get your logs through az webapp log tail? The tail command would be live insight. What would you do if the auditing team asks for logs for your web app? What would you provide to your security if there was a breach?

Comment: I am sorry but no ;) you put 2 links but it does not match to what i see. I only see ftp account in this section and i do not have password..

Comment: I am not following what you mean. The link tells you how to configure App Service Logs. Please read the entire blog. This is what you are asking in your question, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When your web apps service is down you can get more details in "**Diagnose and solve problems**" in azure portal, you can get application logs, container issue, memory usage and other details.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics

If you want to debug your code deployed in app service inside azure portal then you can go to advanced tool and launch **KUDU**.
https://www.gslab.com/blogs/kudu-azure-web-app

Note: You need to have contributor permissions for this.

Comment: Do you know if the contributor permission is still needed? This does not work when implementing a tight enterprise security model.